# trying to detect if three numbers within an array occur in a row

Tags: javascript

I am creating a function which takes in a number value as a parameter. From there, the goal is to detect if three numbers occured in a row, for example 3415633356 would pass as true and 3562455 would not.

I am doing something wrong in my function as scenarios which should be passing as true are not. The end goal of detecting if three numbers in a row occured can be done in any way.

By the way, I am new to programming and just starting out so I'm trying to increment my knowledge as I practice these things. If you can breakdown why your suggesstion works and what I am doing wrong instead of just providing the sole answer, that would be hugely appreciated. Many thanks!

```
var testNumbers = function(num1){
  var stringOne = num1.toString();
  var num1array = stringOne.split("");
  var tripleNum = [];
  num1array.reduce(function(a,b){
    if (a===b){
      tripleNum.push(a);
    }
  })
  if (tripleNum.length >= 3){
    console.log(tripleNum);
  } else {
    console.log("There wasnt a case of three straight triple numbers occuring");
  }

}
```

Comment: Not really. It's just a scenario that I have to work around to achieve the end goal of detecting if three numbers occured in a row. It can be done in any way, as long as that goal is achieved. I thought reduce may have been the best way to go about it since it compares each element, but as stated I am still new to the world of programming so I am aware I may have gone about it completely the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be done with a regex :)

```
var testNumbers = function(num1){
  var stringOne = num1.toString();
  var regEx = /111|222|333|444|555|666|777|888|999|000/;

  if (regEx.test(stringOne)){
    console.log(stringOne.match(regEx)[0]);
  } else {
    console.log("There wasnt a case of three straight triple numbers occuring");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, programming for fun. I must admit, I havent come across this regEx concept as I've been progressing in my Javascript studies, but its certainly something I will now look into! Many thanks once again :)

Comment: This is simpler :)  regEx = /(\d)(?=\1\1)/

Answer (score 1):

I would keep a counter that gets increased every time a new number equals a past number. If that count gets to three we quite and return true. Otherwise if the loop ends, we return false. For example:

```js
function count3(arr) {
  // initialize a counter
  let count = 1
  
  // loop through the array, starting with the second
  // element, so we can compare it to the first
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  
    // does the count equal the previous?
    // if so increase it, otherwise set it back to 1
    count = arr[i] === arr[i - 1] ? count + 1 : 1 // <-- ternary operator
    // see if we're done
    if (count === 3) return true
  }
  // never reached three
  return false
}

// try it out
var arr = [3, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5]
console.log(count3(arr))

var arr = [3, 3, 4, 1, 5,5,5, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5]
console.log(count3(arr))

// make sure it works when array ends with three
var arr = [ 5, 6, 7, 3, 3, 3]
console.log(count3(arr))

// with strings too?
console.log(count3('34156335666'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response Mark_M! :)

Comment: @jimmy118 Hope it helps. Good luck.